# dynamodb rolling averages field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a dynamodb table with columns
Id, Count, TotalNumber, AverageNumber

Every minute or so a new number is written so it will add to TotalNumber, now how would I grab the current count and TotalNumber by count to then calculate a rolling average?

```
attrNames["#number"] = "totalNumber";
attValues[":n"] = number;

attrNames["#count"] = "count";
attValues[":c"] = 1;

var params = {
    Key: { id: id},
    TableName: "myTable",
    UpdateExpression: "Add #number :n, #count :c",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: attrNames,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: attValues,
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
};  
console.log(params);

dynamo.updateItem(params, function(err,res){
    console.log(err);
});
```

I know that i would need a

```
var getParams ={ Key: { id: id},
    TableName: "myTable",
};
```

But where would i go from there?

Answer (score 1):

How many numbers will you have? You can store numbers sorted by their incoming order (range key), and then calculate rolling average by storing rolling sum and adding new number and subtracting oldest number on every write.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question right but DynamoDB doesn't support aggregation queries in the way that a relational database would.

If all you're trying to do is query for a specific item (ie. you have the ID) and want to update said item with a `Count / TotalNumber` value for the average then you can definitely do that, though it would be two requests: one query, and one update with the update values computed by the client.

But if you're looking to update several items with a single query then that does not work (meaning that you would have to write client logic to query for the items and then issue update requests for each item separately).

The same applies for the aggregation case. If you need to update an item based on a query that involves multiple other items then you have to first query to collect the source data and then issue the update with the computed values from the client.